# matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to catch an exception but does not work.This is the code in my view:

```
@login_required 
def activities_edit(request, edit):

    ActivityFormSet = modelformset_factory(Activity, can_delete=True)
    act_edit= Activity.objects.filter(campaing=1).get(pk=edit)
    try:
        if act_edit:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                formset = ActivityFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=Activity.objects.filter(pk=edit))       
                if formset.is_valid():
                    formset.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/activities/')
            else:
                formset = ActivityFormSet(queryset=Activity.objects.filter(pk=edit))
    except act_edit.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/activities/')
```

I was also trying with: " except act_edit.DoesNotExist: "
but the error persists "Activity matching query does not exist."
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: in javascript its usually try catch, not try except

Comment: The `filter(campaing=1)` is reduntant if you know the `pk`.

Comment: Use `get_object_or_404`, forget exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the statement that can cause the exception in the body of the `try:` clause.

The syntax is "try: *something* catch *stuff*:" your *something* is above the `try:`

```
act_edit= Activity.objects.filter(campaing=1).get(pk=edit)
try:
```

Should be

```
try:
   act_edit = Activity.objects.filter(campaing=1).get(pk=edit)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a little bit of redundancy catching the exception means you don't have to check if act_edit is empty because if it is empty it will raise DoesNotExist.   Also the model has the `DoesNotExist` not the instance.

```
@login_required 
def activities_edit(request, edit):

    ActivityFormSet = modelformset_factory(Activity, can_delete=True)       
    try:
        act_edit= Activity.objects.filter(campaing=1).get(pk=edit)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = ActivityFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=Activity.objects.filter(pk=edit))       
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/activities/')
        else:
            formset = ActivityFormSet(queryset=Activity.objects.filter(pk=edit))
            #HttpResponse not returned error here.
    except Activity.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/activities/')
```